# get latitude and longitude when click POI at google map javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get POI's latitude and longitude when click POI. As you can see there is POI's latitude and longitude included on URL bottom of the image.

I think it's not available at documentation.

I remember that google map api for Android provide POI's latitude and longitude when I tested 3 months ago.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps use the Places API (or the Google Maps JavaScript API v3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a latitude and longitude of the POI when you click on it, you should add a click event listener on the map object. Each time you click on the POI, the map will trigger an event of type `google.maps.IconMouseEvent`:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#IconMouseEvent

You just need to check if event has `placeId` field and stop event propagation to prevent default info window if it is necessary.

Have a look at the following example that demonstrates how to extract place ID and coordinates of POIs.

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 41.3850639, lng: 2.1734035},
    zoom: 19
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  map.addListener('click', function(event){
    if (event.placeId) {
      event.stop();
      infowindow.close();
      infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
      infowindow.setContent(
        '<div>'
        + '<strong>You clicked place</strong><br>' 
        + 'Place ID: ' + event.placeId + '<br>' 
        + 'Position: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() + '</div>');
      infowindow.open(map);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

I hope this helps!